# Cognos: Read HTML code in PDF

Tags: html, pdf, formatting, cognos

Is it possible to use HTML format code in PDF?
For example, when the field is `<b>Test<b>` the PDF shows test in bold?

Like putting a setting to a text item that it should read the text as 'HTML'?

Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure you check your post in the preview pane in the future. SO strips tags by default, making your "when the field is Test..." sentence rather hard to understand. To show HTML tags in your post, surround the text with `\`` backticks. I've edited your question for you to show the `<b>` tags

Comment: *open the HTML file in browser , print it as PDF.*

Comment: We schedule it as PDF - so it runs automatically as PDF. And the HTML text does not show up in bold.

Comment: So you have HTML formatted data in your database and you want to apply the HTML formatting in PDF?

Answer (score 1):

No, HTML encoded formatting will not display the way you want in PDF.

You must design your Cognos reports in Report Studio.  Formatting applied through Report Studio will display correctly in HTML or PDF versions of your report.

Answer (score 0):

`Rich Text Item` will almost do what you want.

This control will show on PDF and you can also load it from a database. But it only supports basic tags.

`<b>TEST</b>` is not valid for this control, However the following link shows how you might be able to approximate this.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.1.0.doc%2Fug_cr_rptstd_id23310rich_text_item_supported_elements.html